# Modular arithmetic question.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What solutions does the equation $4x≡2\mod 10$ have? (Hint, it will have more that one.)  What about solutions to an equation $ax≡d \mod n$, where $d=\gcd(a,n)$?
This is the question that appear in our universities last year paper. But it is seems very difficult for me like for first part I am able to solve by simplifications I got $x=5.Z+3$ as solution which makes sense and seems fair but for the second one I have no idea how can I approach that. Can you please help me out with that one. I tried to simplify that by using Euclidean algorithm but still I didn't get any idea that what actually the solution will be. My final exam is on 2nd of next month and because of covid I am unable to contact in person for any help. So any help from this site will be appreciated. Thanks you for looking at this question!

Comment: The congruence $ax\equiv d\bmod n$ with $d=\gcd(a,n)$ is equivalent to the congruence $(a/d)x\equiv1\bmod{n/d}$, and $\gcd(a/d,n/d)=1$.

Comment: This question is at least virtually word for word the same as the one you asked about an hour earlier. Please don't repeat the same question multiple times.

Comment: I apologize for that but i thought it was just missed!

Comment: Won't happen next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better for you to understand the first-degree linear congruence equations in full generality rather than the particular case you posted.

**Theorem.** The congruence equation $ax\equiv b\pmod{n}$ has solutions if and only if ${\rm gcd}(a,n)\mid b$.

*Proof*. $(\Rightarrow)$ Let $x$ be a solution of the congruence equation. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $ax=b+kn$ and from the [Bézout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we can infer that $b$ must be a multiple of ${\rm gcd}(a,n)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $d:={\rm gcd}(a,n)$ and write $b=db_1$, $a=da_1$ and $n=dn_1$. The congruence equation can be thus simplified to
$$
a_1x\equiv b_1\pmod{n_1}.
$$
Note that ${\rm gcd}(a_1,n_1)=1$, thus $a_1$ is invertible modulo $n_1$ (basically by Bézout identity again) and hence $x\equiv a_1^{-1}b_1\pmod{n_1}$ are the solutions of the initial congruence equation. $\Box$

As for your example, you can divide both sides (and the modulus!) by $2$, yielding $2x\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. Then, following the second part of the above proof, note that $3$ is an inverse of $2$ modulo $5$ and thus the solutions of the congruence equation are $x\equiv 3\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As $4$ and $100$ are not coprime, $4$ has no inverse mod $10$, so you have to resort to the *Chinese remainder theorem* and solve both, since $10=2\cdot 5$,
\begin{cases}
4x\equiv 2\equiv 0\mod 2 &\text{(satisfied by any $x$)}\\
4x\equiv 2 \mod5
\end{cases}
So you have to multiply both sides of the last congruence by the inverse of $4\bmod 5$, then combine both solutions to obtain solution  $\bmod 10$ via the inverse isomorphism
$$\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate this hint, it helps a lot